# How binding XML File to ComboBox?

Tags: c#

i want make a **Country ComboBox**, how i binding this **XML** file to **ComboBox** , this my code:

```
public class CountriesComboBox : ComboBox
{

    public CountriesComboBox()
    {
        XDocument obj = XDocument.Load("countries.xml");
        //DisplayMember = "countryiso";
        //ValueMember = "countrycode";
        DataSource = obj.Descendants("country").Select(x => new
        {
            countrycode = x.Attribute("code").Value,
            countryiso = x.Attribute("name").Value
        }).ToList();
    }

}
```

and this my XMl file:

```
<countries>
  <country code="AF" iso="4">Afghanistan</country> 
  <country code="AL" iso="8">Albania</country> 
  <country code="DZ" iso="12">Algeria</country> 
  <country code="AS" iso="16">American Samoa</country> 
  <country code="AD" iso="20">Andorra</country> 
  <country code="AO" iso="24">Angola</country> ....
```

Comment: what technology? wpf?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're in the right track.

1. Create a class that represents you Countries in the combobox: **CountryView**
2. Put properties there: code, iso, name, etc...
3. parse your xml like you're doing and create instances of CountryView.
4. Set your datasource to your list
5. Set the displayMember and displayValue accordingly: each to a property name in your class
6. For better performance cache your list of countries (if they do not change which i guess it's a pretty immutable list)

From you question you're currently trying to bind to an anonymous type. I've never tried and i rather have a named-class for that need.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this out:-**

```
public class CountriesComboBox : ComboBox
{

    public CountriesComboBox()
    {
        XDocument obj = XDocument.Load("countries.xml");
        //DisplayMember = "countryiso";
        //ValueMember = "countrycode";
        DataSource = obj.Descendants("country").Select(x => new
        {
            countrycode = x.Attribute("code").Value,
            countryiso = x.Attribute("iso").Value
        }).ToList();
    }

}
```

Use `x.Attribute("iso").Value` instead of `x.Attribute("name").Value`.

Comment: @johny- Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it for WPF.

```
comboBox1.ItemsSource = xdoc.Root.Descendants("country").Select(x => x.Value);
```